# How do I search in Laravel using selects?

Tags: laravel

On my test site I have a search by cities and categories, which are selected using a select

```
<div class="form-group">   
    <select class="selectpicker" name="sCity">
        @foreach($cities as $city)
            <option value="{{$city->slug}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
    <select class="selectpicker" name="sCat">
        @foreach($categories as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->slug}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

And such a method for searching

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $result = DB::table('ads')
        ->where('city_slug',  $request->sCity)
        ->orWhere('category_slug', $request->sCat)
        ->get();

    dd($result);    
}
```

If you search for one select, then the search is correct, but if you set values ​​to two selections at once, then only the first is triggered, and the second is ignored. How can you fix this?

Comment: this because you use orWhere: use where instead of orWhere. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: This works if you search for two selects, but does not work if you search for one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result1 = DB::table('ads')
        ->where('city_slug',  $request->sCity)
        ->get();

$result2 = DB::table('ads')
        ->where('category_slug', $request->sCat)
        ->get();
$result = $result1->merge($result2):
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

in your view

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="selectpicker" name="sCity">
        <option value=0>please select one</option>
        @foreach($cities as $city)
        <option value="{{$city->slug}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="selectpicker" name="sCat">
        <option value=0>please select one</option>
        @foreach($categories as $cat)
        <option value="{{$cat->slug}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
```

and in your controller

```
$city_slug='';
$category_slug='';
        if($request->sCity!=0)
        {
            $city_slug=' city_slug='.$request->sCity;
        }
        if($request->sCat!=0)
        {
            $category_slug=' or category_slug='.$request->sCat;
        }

$result = DB::table('ads')
        ->whereRaw($city_slug.$category_slug)
        ->get();

dd($result);
```